# Handle dynamic xml files using python

Tags: python

Please help me to convert the below xml file to csv format using python.

I am getting an xml file like the below one formatted like excel. But, I would like to convert it to csv format.

My original file has more number of columns and rows. And each file is different with more or less number of columns. I am unable to paste the entire code here. But, here is the definition for tables, rows and columns in xml.

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="3" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:Width="57.5"/>
   <Column ss:Width="49.5"/>
   <Row ss:Height="14.5">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Time</Data><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Language</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2021-02-15T00:00:00.000</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">1899-12-31T22:46:17.000</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Norwegian</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2021-02-15T00:00:00.000</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">1899-12-31T22:23:34.000</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Norwegian</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
```

My Expected Output is as below:

```
Date,Time,Language
2/15/2021,22:46,Norwegian
2/15/2021,22:23,Norwegian
```

Comment: You could use the [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module from the Python standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library like pandas to read the excel file and convert it to CSV format. It'll do all the overhead of converting excel XML files. Here's a snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel (r'your_file_path.xlsx')
data.to_csv (r'you_ouput_file_path.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Once you have the `data` read then you can do whatever you want with it.